# Debuggear en Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quisiera preguntaros si conocéis alguna forma de debuggear eficientemente en Spyder incluyendo puntos de parada en varios módulos.

Al depurar el archivo, tengo la sensación de que los está ignorando.

Mi versión de Spyder es la 3.2.6, y utilizo Python 3.6.

Muchas gracias de antemano, y que tengáis buen fin de semana.

Comment: El mismo IDE te permite poner los puntos donde quieres depurar tu código.

Answer (score 0):

Me imagino que pones puntos de parada en módulos externos y tienes la sensación de que los ignora, ya que que ejecuta ese código externo sin ingresar en la ejecución paso a paso. Lo que debes hacer en ese caso, cuando llegues al punto de ruptura de ese código externo es presionar el botón **Ingresar en la función o método actual** o **CTRL+F11** en la configuración por defecto.

De todos modos debuggear es una cuestión de utilizar múltiples herramientas, prints, logging, pydebugger y mucha artesanía.